# use scrapy in threading

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, scrapy

I am crawling a website that has more than 15K items that I want to crawl and
I used to make 2 selenium threads, one of them was collecting only new items and appending them to a list and the other one only was crawling the URLs which was on the list that the first thread was appending to it.
but selenium wasn't very fast at crawling and my VPS resources weren't enough to open multiple crawlers. so I ended up using the same method but the difference is that the second thread should be scrapy
I mean the first thread is selenium and collects new URLs and the second thread is scrapy and crawls URLs
I write the scrapy code so it works if I give it the URLs manually but when I put it on threads it doesn't do anything
I defined a spider class and I call the class like this:

```
def crawler_runner(barrier, list_of_new=None, Number_Of_New_Ticket = None):
    global list_of_new_hrefs
    while True:
        list_of_thread = list_of_new_hrefs.copy()
        if len(list_of_thread) == 0:
            print('Nothing to crawl...\n')
            pass
        else:
            if len(list_of_thread) > 100:
                list_of_thread= list_of_thread[0:100]

            else:
                list_of_thread = list_of_thread


        
            if "twisted.internet.reactor" in sys.modules:
                print('deleting reactor')
                del sys.modules["twisted.internet.reactor"]
            s = get_project_settings()
            s['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
            s['CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP'] = 30
            s['LOG_LEVEL'] = 'CRITICAL'
            s['DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES'] = {
                'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
                'divar_crawler.middlewares.TooManyRequestsRetryMiddleware': 543,
                'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
                'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
                'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RetryUserAgentMiddleware': 401,
            }
            process = CrawlerProcess(s)

            QuotesSpider.start_urls = list_of_thread
            process.crawl(QuotesSpider, crawl_links = list_of_thread)
            process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
            
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: somewhere I read that we can't use scrapy in threads and if so, how can I achieve my need?

Comment: Can you playwright to scrape the contents? its much faster than selenium

Comment: the site I was trying to crawl somehow returns 429 error code to scrapy which means too many requests, but this error never happened to me when I was working with selenium,
so I ended up using multiprocessing with selenium, I found some prefs for selenium and those prefs reduced ram usage a lot (with 30 chrome tabs my chrome ram usage is about 500M)

Comment: 429 error code suggest you are experiencing `IP rate limitation.`  Hence being blocked . The solution of this problem is not threading.  

1. you can try using proxies and Rotate them. Or you can use a solution like `scrapy-rotating-proxies` middleware to configure multiple proxies in your spider and have requests rotate through them.

2. you can try  Rotating `USER_AGENT`.
One way to navigate this filter is to switch your `USER_AGENT` to a value copied from those that popular web browsers use.

3. You can try inspecting developer tools and `reverse engineer` the request parameters.

Comment: @Neha Setia Nagpal i tried to do that but it didn't work